# Sum of sums from tables of line items SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:
CUSTOMERS
CLOSEDORDERS
CLOSEDORDERARCHIVES

Each is linked by a customer ID field.  CLOSEDORDERS and CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVES are tables with every line item of every invoice ever sold.  I'm trying to come up with lifetime totals for the customers, but I'm stuck on the final sum.  Here is what I have written, it outputs correct totals for each table in two columns (some of the values are null):

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.Company, CUSTOMERS.[Ship City], CUSTOMERS.[Ship State], 
      (SELECT SUM (CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE.Quantity*CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE.SellPrice) 
      FROM CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE 
      WHERE CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.ID) AS archiveTotal, 
            (SELECT SUM (CLOSEDORDERS.Quantity*CLOSEDORDERS.SellPrice)
            FROM CLOSEDORDERS
            WHERE CLOSEDORDERS.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.ID) AS currentTotal
FROM CUSTOMERS, CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE, CLOSEDORDERS
WHERE (((CUSTOMERS.Branch)=33));
```

When I search, I find this answer that seems similar, but I can't make it work, is it because the sums are summed from line items in the tables and grouped by customer?  Also, this is one of my first queries, is there a more efficient way to write/accomplish this?

[Sum of sums in different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658028/sum-of-sums-in-different-tables)

Answer (score 0):

We can break this into a simpler problem first: Put everything you need in one table.

If the only columns required for the sum are the quantities and sellprices (and the ID of course) you can union them in a subquery and calculate the total of that later. The subquery will look something like:

```
select CustomerID as 'ID', Quantity as 'Quantity', SellPrice as 'SellPrice'
from CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE

UNION ALL

select CustomerID as 'ID', Quantity as 'Quantity', SellPrice as 'SellPrice'
from CLOSEDORDERS
```

After that, you can select from that subquery and group by customer ID and you'll get the sum totals for each customer:

```
select ID, SUM(Quantity*SellPrice) from(

select CustomerID as 'ID', Quantity as 'Quantity', SellPrice as 'SellPrice'
from CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE

UNION ALL

select CustomerID as 'ID', Quantity as 'Quantity', SellPrice as 'SellPrice'
from CLOSEDORDERS
) as subq1
GROUP By ID
```

And I think that's what you need. You can even join the last query with the table Customers if you want the customer name and stuff like that to appear =)

Comment: When I try to run this I get, "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Comment: What line does it say? I can't find the sintax error here

Comment: It highlights the first "UNION ALL" line.  This is in Access, I don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: Jesus I had no idea this was access. I learned just a little bit back in the day but I believe that instead of "union all" you should just put "union". Also I believe that the syntax for the subquery is still right for access. What I don't know is if you still need to put semicolons after every from in the subquery.

Comment: This works and is a nice solution, but it assumes that all companies have made orders. If a company hasn't yet made an order, it won't show up in the results. I assume the asker still wants to list them, just with a total of "0". To guarantee all companies are listed regardless of orders, you probably have to start with CUSTOMERS and do at least one outer join. See my answer.

Comment: @AlvinThompson you're right. You could and most likely should start with a left joined customer. I said to do it at the end because I thought it'd be easier to understand that way, and also because the post main topic was doing a "sum of sums" so I figured I'd do that first.

Comment: @Damieh - Yep, I missed that part of your answer! jgiblets - if you do it that way, remember that it has to be an outer join--a right outer join in that case, and you'll have to check for NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think least unintuitive solution is to join on subqueries (ugh!). Here's an (oversimplified, see caveat below) example:

```
SELECT
  c.Company,
  c.[Ship City],
  c.[Ship State],
  co.Total + coa.Total AS 'Grand Total'
FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Quantity*SellPrice) as 'Total'
  FROM CLOSEDORDERS
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS 'co' ON c.ID = co.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Quantity*SellPrice) as 'Total'
  FROM CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS 'coa' ON c.ID = coa.CustomerID
WHERE c.Branch = 33
```

In this case, we're creating two intermediate tables (co and coa) which hold CLOSEDORDERS's and CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE's order totals for each customer listed in the table.

Caveat: if there are no orders in CLOSEDORDERS or CLOSEDORDERSARCHIVE for a company, than co.Total (or coa.Total) will be NULL for that company. You need to check for this or the addition will be wrong (IIRC NULL + a number = NULL). So the "co.Total" and "coa.Total" expressions of the SELECT clause should use a COALESCE or CASE statement to check for it. Something like:

```
...COALESCE(co.Total,0) + COALESCE(coa.Total,0) AS 'Grand Total'...
```

Comment: IIRC SQL server doesn't like the `AS` after the subquery, so Access may be the same way. It's optional so you can remove it if it gives you trouble: `) 'co' ON c.ID = co.CustomerID`.

Comment: SQL Server does like the "as" before the subquery name. I do it all the time, trust me =)